# Input field with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created an `input` field where users can type in whatever they want to search for. I have also created a drop down list but the list exceeds the page and only few items are shown.

So, I also wanted to create scroll bar to easily access all the items. The code looks like below and there are almost 200 items.

Thank you in advance.

```css
body {
  background: #2196F3;
  font-family: "calibri", sans-serif;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  margin: 0;
}

#head {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1C2833;
}

.box {
  height: 30px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: large;
  color: #17202A;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <form id="form1">
      <input class="box" list="Country" name="Countries" placeholder=" Country">
      <datalist id="Country">
        <option value=" Afghanistan">
        <option value=" Albania">
        <option value=" Algeria">
        <option value=" American Samoa">
        <option value=" Andorra">
        <option value=" Angola">
        <option value=" Anguilla">
        <option value=" Antigua and Barbuda">
        <option value=" Argentina">
        <option value=" Armenia">
        <option value=" Aruba">
        <option value=" Australia">
        <option value=" Austria">
        <option value=" Azerbaijan">
        <option value=" Bahamas">
        <option value=" Bahrain">
        <option value=" Bangladesh">
        <option value=" Barbados">
        <option value=" Belarus">
        <option value=" Belgium">
        <option value=" Belize">
        <option value=" Benin">
        <option value=" Bermuda">
        <option value=" Bhutan">
        <option value=" Bolivia">
        <option value=" Bosnia and Herzegovina">
        <option value=" Botswana">
        <option value=" Brazil">
        <option value=" British Virgin Islands">
        <option value=" Brunei">
        <option value=" Bulgaria">
      </datalist>
    </form>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to try and format your code better here, also can you show the CSS you currently have? The CSS overflow property will automatically add a scroll bar if the content overflows an element's box.

Comment: By default a `datalist` provides a scrollbar. Is your CSS affecting something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll bar for Datalist in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042745/scroll-bar-for-datalist-in-html5)

Answer (score 1):

Please, check this snippet:

```html
<form action="somepage.php" method="get">
 <input list="Country" name="Country">
 <datalist id="Country">
  <option value=" Afghanistan">
  <option value=" Albania">
  <option value=" Algeria">
  <option value=" American Samoa">
  <option value=" Andorra">
  <option value=" Angola">
  <option value=" Anguilla">
  <option value=" Antigua and Barbuda">
  <option value=" Argentina">
  <option value=" Armenia">
  <option value=" Aruba">
  <option value=" Australia">
  <option value=" Austria">
  <option value=" Azerbaijan">
  <option value=" Bahamas">
  <option value=" Bahrain">
  <option value=" Bangladesh">
  <option value=" Barbados">
  <option value=" Belarus">
  <option value=" Belgium">
  <option value=" Belize">
  <option value=" Benin">
  <option value=" Bermuda">
  <option value=" Bhutan">
  <option value=" Bolivia">
  <option value=" Bosnia and Herzegovina">
  <option value=" Botswana">
  <option value=" Brazil">
  <option value=" British Virgin Islands">
  <option value=" Brunei">
  <option value=" Bulgaria">
 </datalist>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

There's something different in your case?

**EDIT**
This is what I see in Firefox
[image]

This is what I see in Chrome
[image]

**EDIT 2**

From my knowledge, you currently can't style the `<datalist>` tag.

Comment: His issue is that it will not add a scrollbar to go through each country, the list more than likely fills up the entire page. This one does not either. That is odd in Mozilla, there is no dropdown. While in Chrome, there is a dropdown but no scrollbar.

Comment: I understand and believe that's currently isn't possible to do that... why not try a Combobox?

Comment: Yes I want to achieve exactly the same thing in chrome, like the one shows in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change  the height of an option you can only change the font size of option

```css
  #country option{ font-size:5px}
```

check this for more information[a link](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#country option {
  overflow:scroll;
 }
```

try without and with option, not sure how that will make a difference.