# Display only 5 records in the autocomplete <input> tag bound with the <datalist> tag items and for rest items show the scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

When I click in the input tag then countries is shown in the drop down.

My Problem: I just want to show only 5 countries in the list and want to show scroll for rest number of countries in the list.

I have tried putting scroll, height to the data list but it does not seem to work for me.

```
<input id="input-id" list="country-datalist" type="text" placeholder="Select country" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="country-datalist">
    <div ng-repeat="country in CountryList">
        <option> {{country.name}} </option>
    </div>
</datalist>
```

Comment: @NTP Thanks. But, the question was asked in the 2014 and thought some new things might have come.

Comment: I posted the the answer for your question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23042745/scroll-bar-for-datalist-in-html5/54321289#54321289)..Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v30gqws5/9/. If you find useful please upvote it.

Comment: @dev9 While typing in the input text the drop down list is getting changed to original and shows all the result matching the input text which is not limited to 5.

Any way thanks.